# Drupal Commerce 2 Promote Product to Front Page

Tags: 8, commerce

I am using drupal commerce 2 to create an ecommerce website. Need to promote some products to front page but there is no option in product types to promote the product to front page. In Drupal Commerce 1 we use to reference the product in product display node and that can be easily promoted to front page. Is there any different method to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Promoted to front page" is an archaism from the early days of Drupal, so it wasn't transferred into Commerce. Nowadays you can create any number of fields, and filter on them:

1) Go to your product type.
2) Create your own boolean field called "Promoted to front page"
3) Use it from your View.